# how to find a file that is NOT executable

Tags: find

i want to find all the files that are not executable.
I know how to find executable files

```
find -executable
```

but I don't know how to do the negation of `-executable`

Answer (score 13):

You can use `!` as a negation for most flags, although you have to escape it in some shells:

```
find \! -executable
```

You can also use `-not` if you are using the GNU version, but it is not POSIX-compliant.

See [`find(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for more information.

Comment: I used that on my bin directory and it listed my scripts as non-executable?@forest

Comment: @fixit7 Are you sure they are executable then? What is their mode (e.g. 755)?

Comment: But why did it list them? -rwxrwxr-x  1 andy andy    234 Apr 15 16:30  Tea.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 andy andy     58 Jun 15  2020  text2file.sh*
@forest

Comment: @fixit7 I don't know. Can you post the entire output, including the command you used?

Comment: Detect_Mouse_Movement.sh  Log2SysLog.sh            Printers_Status.sh               SpeedTest.sh                     Writer_Open_Blank_ODT.sh
Does_File_Exist.sh        LoginBG_Changer.sh       PW_Generator.sh                  StartTerminalMin.sh                                                                                                                  
andy@7 ~/bin> find \! -executable
./PrintWelbyJSC_Register.sh
./Debug-v-n.sh
./my_mouse_log.txt
./cleanup_ at_10:02am_ on_ the_15th.txt
./Suspend.sh @forest

Comment: @MatteoTassinari The comment is not by the OP, it's ok to post it in the comments.

Comment: Oh my, I misread the username, you're right!

Comment: You typically only have to escape it in interactive shells, because it's the history prefix. History expansions are normally disabled in scripts.

Comment: It's not a bad idea to escape ! in scripts too.  People debugging scripts tend to copy bits of them and execute them in an interactive shell.

Comment: @fixit7 The paths should precede the predicate expression (e.g. `find foo.sh bar.sh ! -executable`). I wonder what `find` you're using if it didn't raise an error like GNU's does when putting paths after the condition.